# Moving file using shutil does not work as expected in python

Tags: python, shutil

Trying to move the file from one folder to another but keeps getting this error shown below. I do have this Model.xlsx file in the sample1 source but I am not able to move this. I tried to use 'shutil.move(os.path.abspath(f), dest1)' absolute path but that is giving me different error. it literally picks a random folder. Thanks.

```
import shutil
import os


source = 'D:/Desktop/sample1'
dest1 = 'D:/Downloads/sample2'
dest2 = 'D:/Downloads/sample3'



files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("Model.xlsx")):
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
    elif (f.startswith("Intel") or f.startswith("intel")):
        shutil.move(os.path.abspath(f), dest2)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\KSanala1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 566, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Model.xlsx' -> 'D:/Downloads/sample2\\Model.xlsx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/KSanala1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    shutil.move(f, dest1)
  File "D:\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 580, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "D:\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 266, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "D:\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Model.xlsx'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: when using Windows path in python you need escape the path like this: `source = r'D:/Desktop/sample1'`

Comment: i added yours and kaouther code and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the whole path to shutil.move , which is in your case :
os.path.join(source, f)

```py
files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    f_path = os.path.join(source,f)
    if (f.startswith("Model.xlsx")):
        shutil.move(f_path , dest1)
    elif (f.startswith("Intel") or f.startswith("intel")):
        shutil.move(os.path.abspath(f_path), dest2)
```

Comment: should i put os.path.abspath for the elif statement?

Comment: no there is no need for it ( I just tried to copy what u did and correct it )

Comment: i just added the abspath to both the files.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` only returns a list of filenames. To get the actual path (which you require), you need to joint the original filepath, i.e the argument to `os.listdir` with the filename

```py
files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    fpath = os.path.join(source, f)
```

Now you have a path that makes sense, instead of just a filename.

However mixing hardcoded paths like `source = 'D:/Desktop/sample1'` with `os.path` functions is not a good idea. Consider building the paths using `os.path` in the first place

```py
source = os.path.join('D:', os.sep, 'Desktop', 'sample1')
```

Comment: @KSp please mention *how* it does not work. Don't just say "it doesn't work. The errors are shown for a reason

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort. I got the answer from the other comment.